# click to remove/Deactivate Auxiliary Route in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

When I do click on compose button to open email template (e.g; as given in gmail when click to compose mail), using Auxiliary Route for multiple template in single page.

Question is : how to remove or Deactivate this Auxiliary Route, when click on cross button.

[image: please see image for better explanation]

**app.ts**

```js
   @RouteConfig([
    {
     path: '/',
     name: 'OpportunityList',
     component: OpportunityComponent,
     useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
     path: '/detail',
     name: 'Detail',
     component: DetailComponent
    },
    {
     aux: '/mailer', 
     name: 'Mailer', 
     component: MailerComponent
     }
   ])
```

**app.html**

```js
    <a [routerLink]="['/', ['Mailer'] ]" >Compose</a>
```

**mailer.component.ts**

```js
   export class MailComponent implements OnInit{
      closeEmail(){
          console.log("please suggest me to Deactivate this template")
       }
    }
```

**mailer.component.html**

```js
   <div class="header with-bord">
     <h3 class="title">New Message <a (click)="closeEmail()" class="close"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5122, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325376/auxiliary-routes-in-angular-2-remains-in-the-url-after-navigating-away#36325376 (unaswered)

Answer (score 5):

```
this.router.navigate([{ outlets: { aux: null } }]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!