# Auxiliary routes in Angular 2 remains in the url after navigating away

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to use auxiliary routes to show different content in a sidebar, depending on which route you're on.

The problem is that the auxiliary route remains (both in URL and the content) after navigating away.

**The HTML:**

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="sidebar"></router-outlet>
```

**The RouteConfig:**

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/', name: 'Home', component: Home, useAsDefault: true},
    {path: '/leadslist', name: 'LeadsList', component: LeadsList},
    {aux:'/sidebar', name: 'Sidebar', component: Sidebar}
])
```

**The links in the navbar:**

```
<a [routerLink]="['Home']">Home</a>    
<a [routerLink]="['LeadsList', ['Sidebar']]">Leads list</a>
```

**Current Behaviour:**

1. From the home page, I click the link "Leads list".
2. I am redirected to the route "/leadslist(sidebar)" and the sidebar content is properly loaded in its router outlet. All good so far.
3. If I now click the link "Home" to take me back to "/", the URL is instead "/(sidebar)", which takes me back to the home page but with the sidebar loaded (unwanted behaviour!)

**My question:** How can I navigate to a route without the auxiliary route "tagging along"?

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36220266/click-to-remove-deactivate-auxiliary-route-in-angular-2 (also no answer) See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5122

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently (imho) this could be handled better in the Angular2 router, but what you need to do is set your **`aux` outlet to `null`** and point the **`primary` outlet with the url** you want to go back to.

This works because `primary` is a reserved default outlet for angular2.

Consider the following route: `/inbox/123131$asd(compose:reply)`

In the above route we were viewing an email and composing a reply. So - when we send this we might want the user to get sent back to the main view - the inbox. Then your routerLink would need to look like the following:

```html
<a [routerLink]="['',{outlets: {compose: null, primary: '/inbox'}}]" >Close</a>
```

Be wary that this might be subject to change in the third rewrite of the Angular2 router.